# How to add a common background image to all screens in a stackNavigator in react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a react-native app similar to the [authentication flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) described in react-navigation. I want to add a common background image to all the screens in **AppStack**.

Things I have tried,

- I tried wrapping the **AppStack** navigator inside `<ImageBackground/>` and Somehow the screen card is always on top.

I need help!

Code snippet

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen, SignUp: SignUpScreen });

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
                <View style={{ width: '50%', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                    <Text>Sign in</Text>
                </View>

            </View>
        )
    }
}

class SignUpScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>
                <View style={{ width: '50%', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                    <Text>Sign up</Text>
                </View>

            </View>
        )
    }
}

class Authentication extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={source} style={{ flex: 1 }} >
                <AuthStack />
            </ImageBackground>
        )
    }
}

export default createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
        App: AppStack,
        Auth: Authentication,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Auth',
    }
);
```

Comment: Please post a code snippet of what you have tried for users to understand it better.

Comment: Added code snippet @EdisonD'souza

Comment: @vijaykrishna do you find any solution?

Comment: The approach I used was using image background absolutely positioned in app.js.
and apply 
    cardOverlayEnabled: true,
    transparentCard: true,
in navigation option

Comment: This way the background is visible form all screens.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a color by modifying `cardStyle`, like this:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  { Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen },
  { cardStyle: { backgroundColor: "green" } }
);
```

As far as I know there is no way to set the background image from the styles.

You could though create your own [`CardComponent`.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-views.html)